# Flight Inspiration Search Fail in Production in Self-service

Tags: amadeus

I am running amadeus Flight Inspiration Search, in Production mode

I get error 500 when I use Airport code 'CAI' for Cairo Egypt

I thought all airports are supported by amadeus

Nevertheless, there is no error when I use 'MAD' Airport

```
amadeus = Client(hostname='production',client_id='........)

response = amadeus.shopping.flight_destinations.get(origin='CAI')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flight Inspiration API is built on top of a pre-computed cache, it doesn't contain all the origins and destinations. The Flight Low-fare Search will provide you a coverage of (almost) all airports in the world.

We will update soon the data coverage we have for this API to drastically improve the list of origins and destinations.